# python return number of times a licence used under specific server at specific time from a csv

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, csv

i have a csv file, named user_log.csv. i need to count that how many times each licence on specific server and on every specific time is being used.
The log file csv is like this:

```
Report Date Time,Server,Licence,User,Host,In Use Since Date Time
02/02/2019 11:50,server1,teamcenter_author,user115,TcServer,02/02/2019 11:48
02/02/2019 11:50,server1,teamcenter_consumer,user133,TcServer,02/02/2019 08:57
02/02/2019 11:50,server2,teamcenter_consumer,user31,TcServer,02/02/2019 10:07
02/02/2019 11:50,server1,teamcenter_consumer,user120,TcServer,02/02/2019 10:15
02/02/2019 11:50,server1,visview_base,user120,client1,02/02/2019 05:14
02/02/2019 11:50,server1,visview_base,user12,client2,02/02/2019 07:19
02/02/2019 11:50,server1,visview_base,user95,client3,02/02/2019 11:10
02/02/2019 11:50,server3,NX12100N,user70,client4,02/01/2019 10:54
02/02/2019 11:50,server3,NX12100N_gateway,user70,client4,02/01/2019 10:54
02/02/2019 11:50,server3,NX12100N_solid_modeling,user70,client4,02/01/2019 10:54
02/02/2019 11:55,server1,teamcenter_author,user115,TcServer,02/02/2019 11:48
02/02/2019 11:55,server1,teamcenter_consumer,user133,TcServer,02/02/2019 08:57
02/02/2019 11:55,server1,teamcenter_consumer,user31,TcServer,02/02/2019 10:07
02/02/2019 11:55,server1,teamcenter_consumer,user120,TcServer,02/02/2019 10:15
02/02/2019 11:55,server1,visview_base,user120,client1,02/02/2019 05:14
02/02/2019 11:55,server1,visview_base,user12,client2,02/02/2019 07:19
02/02/2019 11:55,server1,visview_base,user95,client3,02/02/2019 11:10
02/02/2019 11:55,server1,visview_base,user115,TcServer,02/02/2019 11:50
02/02/2019 11:55,server3,NX12100N,user70,client4,02/01/2019 10:54
02/02/2019 11:55,server3,NX12100N_gateway,user70,client4,02/01/2019 10:54
02/02/2019 11:55,server3,NX12100N_solid_modeling,user70,client4,02/01/2019 10:54
```

and the code that i have written is following

```
file = open('/user_log.csv', "r")
reader= csv.reader(file)
time={}
for row in reader:
    licence_name = row[2]
    server = row[1]

    if licence_name in time.keys():
        if server in licence_name:
            time[row[2]][row[1]]['count'] += 1
        else:
            time.setdefault(licence_name,{}).setdefault(server,{})['count'] =1
    else:
        time.setdefault(licence_name,{}).setdefault(server,{})['count']=1

return render(request, "stats.html", {'no_of_line':time})
```

the output i get is something like this:

[image: this]
How shall I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`license_name` is a string, not a dictionary. You want to test whether `server` is in the nested dictionary.

You can use `if license_name in time`, you don't need to use `time.keys()`.

You don't need all the `setdefault()` calls, just create the new dictionaries as you want them. You could instead use that to compress all this code into a single line.

```
file = open('/user_log.csv', "r")
reader= csv.reader(file)
next(reader, None) # Skip the header line
time={}
for row in reader:
    license_name = row[2]
    server = row[1]

    if licence_name in time:
        if server in time[licence_name]:
            time[licence_name][server]['count'] += 1
        else:
            time[licence_name][server] = {"count": 1}
    else:
        time[licence_name] = { server: { "count": 1 } }

return render(request, "stats.html", {'no_of_line':time})
```

The value of `time` I get with this code and the example CSV file is:

```
{'NX12100N': {'server3': {'count': 2}},
 'NX12100N_gateway': {'server3': {'count': 2}},
 'NX12100N_solid_modeling': {'server3': {'count': 2}},
 'teamcenter_author': {'server1': {'count': 2}},
 'teamcenter_consumer': {'server1': {'count': 5}, 'server2': {'count': 1}},
 'visview_base': {'server1': {'count': 7}}}
```

Comment: Can You please help me out if i want to have something like this
'teamcenter_consumer': {'server1': {'11:50' : {'count': 123}, '11:55' : {'count' : 324}}},

Comment: Any reason you're not using something like pandas for this? It has built-in methods for grouping data.

Comment: Add another level of nesting: `if timestamp in time[license_name][server]: time[license_name][server][timestamp] += 1`

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am new at python and i need to deliver the project fast and had no idea of pandas, so i was doing this way

Comment: hey! somehow it does not add a new server name .

Comment: Can you edit the question so the CSV file is plain text instead of an image, so I can copy and paste it?

Comment: Edited the question. please have a look

Comment: I added the result I get, it looks correct. What server name is missing?

Comment: if there are two server, 1 and 2 then server 2 is missing out

Comment: Look at my `teamcenter_consumer` line. It has server1 and server2.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with how you're rendering it

Comment: yepp i got it solved. it was at my end. forgot to add one additional else condition.